# How to associate Azure firewall with an Azure firewall policy?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to associate terraform resource "azurerm_firewall_policy" to "azurerm_firewall"
How can this be done?

I tried to find a resource that associates the "azurerm_firewall_policy" to "azurerm_firewall"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the `firewall_policy_id` argument to the `azurerm_firewall` resource, see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/firewall#firewall_policy_id